# Message: Trying to get property of non-object. CODEIGNITER ERROR CODE

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my controller:

```
public function visualizar(){

    $this->data['custom_error'] = '';
    $this->load->model('mapos_model');        
    $this->data['result'] = $this->financeiro_model->verporid($this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->data['emitente'] = $this->mapos_model->getEmitente();

    $this->data['view'] = 'financeiro/vermovimiento';
    $this->load->view('tema/topo', $this->data);

}
```

This is my model:

```
function verporid($id){
    $this->db->select('lancamentos.*, clientes.*');
    $this->db->from('lancamentos');
    $this->db->join('clientes','clientes.idClientes = lancamentos.clientes_id');        
    $this->db->where('lancamentos.idLancamentos',$id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    return $this->db->get()->row();
}
```

This is my view:

```
 <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>                                 
                                <td style="width: 40%; padding-left: 0">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <span><h5>Cliente</h5>
                                            <span><strong>Nombre: </strong><?php echo $result->nomeCliente?></span><br/>
                                            <span><strong>Dirección: </strong><?php echo $result->rua?>, <?php echo $result->numero?></span><br/> 
                                            <span><strong>Ciudad: </strong><?php echo $result->bairro?>, <?php echo $result->cidade?></span><br/>
                                            <span><strong>Email: </strong><?php echo $result->email?></span><br/>
                                            <span><strong>Teléfono: </strong><?php echo $result->telefone?></span><br/>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td> 
                              </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

And I receive this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: financeiro/vermovimiento.php

Line Number: 32
```

Can somebody help me identify the problem?

Comment: what is actually on `Line Number: 32` because it is not very obvious from the code you have supplied?

Comment: that's just one of the error messages,
the line number 32 is:
    `<span><strong>Nombre: </strong><?php echo $result->nomeCliente?></span><br/>`
all the lines that have the `$result`  string show error

Comment: `var_dump($result)`. It may be null. If it is then encapsulate your table html inside `if(!empty($result))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friend,do like this.
In your view page, you are getting $result array.

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
   <tr>                                 
 <td style="width: 40%; padding-left: 0">
   <ul>
   <li>
 <span><h5>Cliente</h5>
<span><strong>Nombre: </strong>
<?php 

foreach($result as $data)
{
echo $data->nomeCliente;
}
?></span><br/>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </td> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you could try is instead of row() on model is row_array()

```
function verporid($id){
    $this->db->select('lancamentos.*, clientes.*');
    $this->db->from('lancamentos');
    $this->db->join('clientes','clientes.idClientes = lancamentos.clientes_id');        
    $this->db->where('lancamentos.idLancamentos', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row_array();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Then on your controller

```
public function visualizar(){

    $this->data['custom_error'] = '';
    $this->load->model('mapos_model');     

    if ($this->uri->segment(3)) {

        $some_info_data = $this->financeiro_model->verporid($this->uri->segment(3));

        $this->data['nomeCliente'] = $some_info_data['nomeCliente'];

        $this->data['rua'] = $some_info_data['rua'];
        $this->data['numero'] = $some_info_data['numero'];

        $this->data['bairro'] = $some_info_data['bairro'];
        $this->data['cidade'] = $some_info_data['cidade'];

        $this->data['email'] = $some_info_data['email'];
        $this->data['telefone'] = $some_info_data['telefone'];

    }

    $this->data['view'] = 'financeiro/vermovimiento';

    $this->load->view('tema/topo', $this->data);

}
```

View

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>                                 
<td style="width: 40%; padding-left: 0">
<ul>
<li>
<span><h5>Cliente</h5>
<span><strong>Nombre: </strong><?php echo $nomeCliente;?></span><br/>
<span><strong>Dirección: </strong><?php echo $rua;?>, <?php echo $numero;?></span><br/> 
<span><strong>Ciudad: </strong><?php echo $bairro;?>, <?php echo $cidade;?></span><br/>
<span><strong>Email: </strong><?php echo $email;?></span><br/>
<span><strong>Teléfono: </strong><?php echo $telefone;?></span><br/>
</li>
</ul>
</td> 
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```